# calling UIActivityViewController from a different class

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app, I have this aViewController with a method -(void)ShareThis. It does many things, including calling an UIActivityViewController, to share things via email and social media.

I also have bViewController and cViewController, from which I would like to access that -(void)ShareThis method. Currently I just repeat the code in all controller classes, but that feels stupid, and is a pain to maintain.

I tried changing -(void)ShareThis into +(void)ShareThis, but then ran into the issue that I couldn't run methods specific to aViewController within +(void)ShareThis.

In short: I feel I lack some knowledge/understanding on how to tackle this. Could any of you help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should probably be doing with this is removing all of these methods from aViewController completely and put them into a class that is there specifically for sharing stuff from your app.

Then you can either create this shareClass in B and C controller.

Or you can create it in A and then pass it into B and C as a property. Either way will work.

This ShareClass would be a subclass of NSObject and would contain all of the code necessary to sharing stuff.

Comment: I guess that is the way. By doing do, I run into another impossibility, but I'll just live with it.

Comment: Nothing is "impossible" if you have the correct architecture supporting your app. What is the other "impossibility?

Comment: Well, inside my  -(void)ShareThis, I have a routine, that, if the UIActivityViewCOntroller was successful at sharing, a method local to the ViewCOntroller calling  -(void)ShareThis remotely.

Comment: Sorry: to be more clear: Currently, there is a condition that fires off a method on the ViewController that is calling  -(void)ShareThis. Since  -(void)ShareThis is now on another class, it is not aware of the localities of that method

Comment: Set it up using a delegate protocol. `if (someCondition) { [self.delegate doSomething];}`